# How to delete all text appearing between two symbols with sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file with lines like this:

```
bear/forest/\AAA mountains/fish/
fish/\AAA stream/river/\AAA shrimp/
llama/mountains/
```

I want to delete any text appearing between 2 `/`'s, where `\AAA` appears, e.g., the above would become:

```
bear/forest/fish/
fish/river/
llama/mountains/
```

`AAA` always appears after the first `/` symbol.

I have tried to make a find and replace, matching the pattern `/\AAA*/` and replacing it with `/`, but this did not work:

```
sed -i -r 's/\/\\AAA*\//\//g' file.txt
```

I have GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: `*` is a metacharacter meaning zero or more of the preceeding character or group. So `A*` means zero or more `A`'s. You must supply `\(AAA\)*` to mean zero or more `AAA`'s. However what you intended  was `[/][^/]*AAA[^/]*[/]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove everything between `/\AAA` and `/`. Using an alternative character to separate the patterns improves readability, if the pattern or replacement contain `/`:

```
sed 's,/\\AAA[^/]*/,/,g'
```